# Promise chaining with success and reject functions

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Given a bit of code like the following:

```
let p = somePromise
p.then(
    function (response) {
        $scope.resultDetails = response.data;
        return theNextPromise;
    },
    function (error) {
        $scope.resultDetails = error.data;
        return theNextPromise;
    }
).then((result) => { ...do more stuff here });
```

What would one have to do to return a promise from this to start a chain, if you wanted to return a promise when you either resolve or reject it seems like you would end up duplicating the code. Is this the case or is there something you can do to make this process a bit cleaner

Comment: Just don't return anything from your resolve and reject handlers and then run theNextPromise  after: `p.then( func... , func... ).then( theNextPromise ).then( result => ...`

Comment: @Paulpro [`Promise.prototype.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) accepts a function, not a promise, so `p.then(...).then(() => theNextPromise).then(result => ...)` would be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one? you initialize promise object and keep chaining until you want to finalize the promise.

```
let sequence = Promise.resolve()

sequence = sequence.then(() => {
  return p
});

sequence = sequence.then((response) => {
    $scope.resultDetails = response.data;
    return theNextPromise;
  },
(error) => {
    $scope.resultDetails = error.data;
    return theNextPromise;
  }));

sequence = sequence.then(result => {return promise object})

// finalize
sequence.then(do something)
```